# yes no radio buttons - if 2 or more yes answers display text

Tags: javascript, html

Teaching myself coding and I am using coffeecup software to write a form with yes no radio buttons.  I would like to learn how to write code that will count # of yes answers and if 2 or more yes answers to  then print the text, "look's like you may need my help".

thank you

Comment: Plese, can you post the relevant part of the code, so we can help you better?

Answer (score -1):

```
for (var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++){
if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox' && checkboxes[i].checked) {
    numChecked++;
      if(numchecked > 2){var help = prompt('Do you need help?');
           if(help){location.href='help_page.html'}}}}
```